# JavaScript `onscroll` event standalone (without frameworks)

Tags: javascript

I need a standalone JavaScript `onscroll` event handler (**without** frameworks such as jQuery, Prototype, mootools, etc.), which is also cross browser.

I have searched for one, I can only find thousands of examples using jQuery or Prototype.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener):

```
    function onScrollEventHandler(ev)
    {
        alert(ev);
        //http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#event-type-scroll
    } 

    var el=window;

    if(el.addEventListener)
        el.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollEventHandler, false);   
    else if (el.attachEvent)
        el.attachEvent('onscroll', onScrollEventHandler);
```

Answer (score 9):

See it on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onscroll

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
  // called when the window is scrolled.
}
```

Comment: I need an event handler, I'm trying to avoid overriding existing callbacks.

Comment: `window.onscroll` IS an event handler that fires when scroll is used.

Comment: window.onscroll is a provided existing event handler. I asked for a new one. Found this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: Your question didn't make the sense then, hence no other answers as well but it is good that you found one.

Comment: The function which is passed to addEventListener, is called an event handler. The window.onscroll is called a property, to which you attach an event handler (which is the same function, except it doesn't allow for multiple event listeners).

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: I wont go into further discussion but a callback is when you pass a an argument to a function which itself is a function. The `addEventListner` is utility function that allows you to attach events.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way

```
function ScrollFunction(){ ... }

var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var AddEvent = window[eventMethod];
var scrollEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onscroll" : "scroll";

AddEvent(scrollEvent, ScrollFunction, false);
```